# Repeat random data with Faker

Tags: julia

I want to use Faker data for many rows. My current code only repeats whatever was generated by the Faker library at that moment:

Current output:

```
│ Row │ Identifier │
│     │ String     │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 40D593     │
│ 2   │ 40D593     │
│ 3   │ 40D593     │
```

Desired outputs:

```
│ Row │ Digits │
│     │ String │
├─────┼────────┤
│ 1   │ 23K125 │
│ 2   │ 13K125 │
│ 3   │ 45K125 │
```

`df2 = DataFrame(Identifier = repeat([Faker.bothify("##?###")], outer=[3]))`

I thought I could do something like `Faker.bothify("##?###") * 3`. I suppose there may also be a way to apply it to a dataframe column that was already made, but I can't find a way just looking through the docs quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use a comprehension:

```
df2 = DataFrame(Identifier=[Faker.bothify("##?###") for _ in 1:3])
```

an alternative is to use broadcasting (but for me a comprehension in this case is more natural to use):

```
df2 = DataFrame(Identifier=Faker.bothify.(Iterators.repeated("##?###", 3)))
```

(I assume this is what you want)

and this is the way to apply it to an existing column with `String` eltype. This operation is in-place:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(Identifier=Vector{String}(undef, 3))
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ Identifier │
│     │ String     │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ #undef     │
│ 2   │ #undef     │
│ 3   │ #undef     │

julia> df.Identifier .= Faker.bothify.("##?###")
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "12H314"
 "56G992"
 "23X588"

julia> df
3×1 DataFrame
│ Row │ Identifier │
│     │ String     │
├─────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 12H314     │
│ 2   │ 56G992     │
│ 3   │ 23X588     │
```

Comment: Thanks. Why undef instead of missing?

Comment: For missing it would be more complex to write: `Vector{Union{Missing,String}}(missing, 3)`. The difference is that then the column would allow `missing`. In the code above it can hold only `String` elements.